# Can't select SPAN sibling

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, siblings

Can't understand why this code changes color of DIV element to blue, but doesn't change color of a SPAN element. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#prev ~ div").css("color", "blue");
      $("#prev ~ span").css("color", "red");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="prev">span#prev</span>
  <div>div sibling</div>
  <span>span sibling</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Noticed what if I replace

```
<span id="prev">span#prev</span>
```

with

```
<p id="prev">span#prev</p>
```

both DIV and SPAN change text color.

Thanks!

Comment: This bug is closed in jQuery version 1.3.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you found a bug.

$("#prev ~ span:not(#prev)") works, as does $("#prev").siblings("span").

Comment: Also, $("#prev~span") works in 1.2.6 so it is definitely a bug introduced in 1.3.

Answer (score 4):

This does indeed seem to be a bug. [Report a bug to jQuery](http://dev.jquery.com/report).

http://dev.jquery.com/report

There are a [decent number of sibling selector bugs](http://dev.jquery.com/search?q=~+selector&go=&wiki=on&changeset=on&ticket=on) it seems.

Comment: I have submitted the problem (http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4605). Hope they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an error with JQuery. You should submit this bug to the team and let them fix it.